# Using .= to add to an array in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, arrays

I recently came across the following snippet of code:

```
@$this->responseData[$this->currentTag] .=$data;
```

Which seems to add $data to the array at the specified index. Without error suppression, this causes an error (Undefined index DataKey). The key used was a string "DataKey". and the data was a string.

I cannot find any documentation on using .= with arrays. Why does it give an error?
I do not want to simply suppress the error and move on. And yes, I could just use = instead of .=. The application may be using responseData for string handling as well as array handling (it is very bad code!!).

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: You don't need documentation on using of `.=` with arrays, because it is for concatenation of strings. So, the problem is in accessing to not existent element of array (not in using of `.=`). But you can't modify not existent element (and you can create it with `=`). So, just check, that this element exists in array (if not, just add it).

Comment: that is a string concatenation

example. $a = "Hello ";
$a .= "World!";     // now $a contains "Hello World!"

in your case the content of the current tag + you $data.

Comment: Thanks guys. I do know that .= is for strings, and I see now that I was looking to hard at it and that it is assuming there is a string in there at the index specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [concatenating assignment operaotor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).I dont know actually what do you want to do it with the arrays..Please edit your question on what you need ..The concatening assignment operator  appends the argument on the right side to the argument on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just build an actual array?

```
$tags = [Your query to build the array of all tag data]
$tagnames = array(); // The array for tag names
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tagnames[] = $tag->tagname;
}
print_r($tagnames);
```